# How to remove the character form string using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove character from strings (a-z, A to Z) using jQuery or JavaScript?

```
if str=avc234jw6;
```

I need only 2346.

Comment: `yourString.replace(/[a-z]/ig,'')`

Comment: Come on, did you at least try to google it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `String.replace` with regex `/[a-z]/ig` can do!

```js
var str = "avc234jw6";
var no = parseInt(str.replace(/[a-z]/ig, ""));

console.log(no);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer on non-edited question "How to remove char from strin?"

```js
var removeChar = "a";
var string  = "abc abc abc";

function removeFromString(char, string){
var newString = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
      if(string[i].toLowerCase() == char){
          continue;
      } else {
       newString += string[i];
      }
    }
    return newString;
}

$("#test").html(removeFromString(removeChar, string));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
test
</div>
```